# Dropping floats-- basic CSS layout issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float, fluid-layout

I'm wrestling with a frustrating-- and profoundly basic-- CSS issue that's illustrated by the diagram below, and a js fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nickpish/gfcqdnqf/). I'm trying to achieve a fluid grid layout with floated block elements defined by percentage widths and varying heights, that will linearize-- i.e. change to `width: 100%` at a certain breakpoint (in the fiddle there's a media query @ 768px max-width.) Note that I need the blocks to linearize in a way that "weaves" the two main colunmns together, as shown in the fiddle. I'm having a problem with the floated elements "dropping" and not aligning vertically as desired-- as indicated by the "news/speaking" block in my diagram.

[image: grid layout diagram]

I have tried every masonry-type jquery plugin I can find, and none of them seem to perform in a consistent or reliable way with fluid layouts. I'm also aware of the `inline-block` method, but the quirks/limitations pose their own problems. Additionally, flexbox looks fantastic, but the current limited support is a problem for this project in particular.

I am open to a jquery-based approach-- i.e. forcing certain blocks to align to the bottom of others, but would prefer a css-based one. I realize I can always apply a negative margin to the "dropping" elements, but this is not a very elegant solution.

Any help with this "float dropping" issue is most appreciated.

Comment: Changing `.item.w1` from `float: left` to `display: inline-block;` seems to resolve the problem, but you mentioned "quirks/limitations" with this approach?  https://jsfiddle.net/7Lc7ofm6/

Comment: @RickHitchcock he may have meant applying inline-block to both `.w1` and `.w2`. But yes I see no problems with your solution

Comment: @zgood - yes, I was inded referring to using inline-block for all elements, but haven't yet tried it for only the left floated elements (i.e. `item.w1`). thanks, I will give it a shot on my site.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure what "quirks/limitations" you're running into using `inline-block`, but if you apply it to `.item.w1` only, it seems to work.

You'll also need to remove `float: none` here:

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 768px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  .item.w1, .item.w2 {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4wvxsmLd/)

Comment: Thanks Rick, I will give that a shot and report back. The "quirks/limitations" to which I referred in using `inline-block` instead of `float` for layout are detailed [here](http://joshnh.com/2012/02/07/why-you-should-use-inline-block-when-positioning-elements/); however, as I mentioned above, I haven't tried using it for just some elements, and keeping `float` on others. I'll apply it to my project and see what happens. Thanks for the assistance.